# Pulling text out from a String Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make something that will read a web page and then from there get the contents and search for something inside the web page and just copy that only. I don't know how to make it only copy so much of the string that I want. To make things harder, the web page does not have any CSS on it and is just text. 

For the thing I want to use the code that is being read is

```
"Token":"5acd163ee08b41b801e0863889111e334b5dd8c2e4f0","ID":4,"
```

and i want the output to just be :

```
5acd163ee08b41b801e0863889111e334b5dd8c2e4f0
```

Comment: You probably want [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but your question is pretty hard to answer in its current form.

Comment: Let's see if we can be more specific: How do you tell the difference between what you want and what you don't?

Comment: I edited it to make it a little bit more easy to understand.

Comment: No I am using urllib to read the page. The page doesn't have anything except that text so I don't see how JSON would be helpful since everything is on 1 line of HTML

Comment: "One line of HTML" and then "doesn't have anything except that text" doesn't make sense. Either its HTML, or simply a text page; so which one is it?

Comment: "*To make things harder, the web page does not have any CSS on it and is just text.*": Looks and sounds like JSON. Can you post a sample URL?

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will return the Token value, if the format's always constant and only the values change in the expression above:

```
text = '"Token":"5acd163ee08b41b801e0863889111e334b5dd8c2e4f0","ID":4," '
m = re.search(r'"Token":"([\w]+)"', text)
m.groups()[0]
>>> '5acd163ee08b41b801e0863889111e334b5dd8c2e4f0'
```

Comment: `\w` includes digits; there is no need for the extra `0-9`.

Comment: Ahh good point. I'll correct this now.

Answer (score 0):

The non-regular expression way, using the excellent [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

g = requests.get('http://www.example.com/some-file.txt')
print(g.text.split(',')[0].split(':')[1])
```